# How to use nested variables (dictionary keys) in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

Feel free to suggest or directly edit my question if it's not expressed clearly.

I have some nested variables declared in Ansible like this:

```
# vars/main.yml
parent_key:
  child_key1: "child_value1"
  child_key2: "Resolving: {{ child_key1 }}"
```

But Ansible says: `child_key1 not defined` or something similar.

However, this also doesn't work:

```
# vars/main.yml
parent_key:
  child_key1: "child_value1"
  child_key2: "Resolving: {{ parent_key.child_key1 }}"
```

Ansible says something like `Could not template ...`.

The results are almost the same for Ansible 1.9.4 and Ansible 2.0.0.2.

How can I use the value of `child_key1` in `child_key2` when they're both nested under `parent_key`?

*Note that the same concept without nesting the keys works fine:*

```
# vars/main.yml (without nesting at all)
child_key1: "child_value1"
child_key2: "Resolving: {{ child_key1 }}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. This indeed was working in earlier Ansible versions but Ansible now prevents this.

The problem is you're trying to reference an object which somehow is in the process of being defined.

In [this bug report on Github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/8603) some users were discussing this topic.

---

As for a solution... how about a combination of both. Something like this:

```
key1: &key1 "child_value1"

parent_key:
  child_key1: *key1
  child_key2: "Resolving: {{ key1 }}"
```

Yes that's ugly, but at least prevents you from repeating the values.

Comment: That's great, works for me. I can sympathize with the reasons for removing that functionality, so this is a great compromise.

Comment: Could you explain what the `&` and `*` operators are in this context?

Comment: That's an anchor and a reference to the anchor, part of YAML. You can play around with it [here](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=key1%3A+%26key1+%22child_value1%22%0A%0Aparent_key%3A%0A++child_key1%3A+*key1%0A++child_key2%3A+%22Resolving%3A+%7B%7B+key1+%7D%7D%22&type=json), on the right side you'll see the evaluated objects which will be what Ansible gets after parsing the YAML.